# What signature should a generic method in Java have so that It can accept any <T that implements Iteralbe and stores List<U>> and...?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, generic-collections

I want to create a method that traverses through any collection that stores `ArrayList<U>` - let's call that collection `T`; for example, it can be `LinkedList`, `ArrayList` or any other `Collection`; `U` - is another type which is needed to be memorized; and the method I want to create should return the same collection `T` but it should store `LinkedList<U>` instead.

"Wrong" desired declaration:

```
public <T extends Collection, U> T<LinkedList<U>> rewrap (T<ArrayList<U>> arrayList) {
    T<LinkedList<U>> linkedList = new T<LinkedList<U>>();
    // do some stuff here
    return linkedList;
}
```

I carefully read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) but I didn't find the way how I can achieve my goal.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. Do you want to convert a `Collection<ArrayList<U>>` to a `Collection<LinkedList<U>>`? Can you write the exact type of a sample input and output of that method?

Comment: Sure, I can, @Eran

1) `LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>` transforms into `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>`.
2) `ArrayList<ArrayList<Animal>>` transforms into `ArrayList<LinkedList<Animal>>`.

etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<LinkedList<T>>> C rewrap (Collection<ArrayList<T>> in, Supplier<C> collectionFactory) {

    C out = collectionFactory.get ();

    for (ArrayList<T> list : in) {
      out.add (new LinkedList<T> (list));
    }

    return out;
}
```

Note that you must pass a `Supplier` in order for the method to be able to create an instance of the `Collection` of the desired type.

Usage:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> in = new ArrayList<> ();
in.add (new ArrayList<String> ());
in.get (0).add ("abc");
ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> out = rewrap (in, ArrayList::new);
```

EDIT: You should note that this method doesn't require that the type of the output outer `Collection` is the same as the type of the input outer `Collection`.

For example, you can pass an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` input and get a `HashSet<LinkedList<String>>` output if you pass a `HashSet::new` supplier instead of `ArrayList::new` in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

This will be compliant to your request, but not strictly enforce return collection type to match input type:

```
public <U> List<LinkedList<U>> rewrap(Collection<ArrayList<U>> arrayList) {
    T linkedList = ...
    // do some stuff here
    return linkedList;
}
```

I don't think there is a way for the generic interface to enforce at compile time that the returned list has the same implementation as the Collection that goes in.

Also note you cannot reuse the ingoing collection or call `new T<...>()`. You would have to use reflection or additional method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Eran's answer is nice. If you don't want to pass a supplier however, you might want to resort this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create inner list
    ArrayList<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
    innerList.add("test string 1"); innerList.add("test string 2");
    // add it to outer List twice because why not
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outerList = new ArrayList<>();
    outerList.add(innerList); outerList.add(innerList);
    // rewrap it
    ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> rewrapped = rewrap(outerList);
    System.out.println("rewrapped.");
}

public static <T, C extends Collection<LinkedList<T>>> C rewrap (Collection<ArrayList<T>> in) {

    Collection<LinkedList<T>> out = null;
    try {
        out = (in.getClass().newInstance());
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    C myC = (C) out;

    for (ArrayList<T> list : in) {
        myC.add (new LinkedList<T> (list));
    }

    return myC;
}
```

Of course, you'd need some better exception handling, but this example code works as I expected it to.